# Шифрование/расшифровка и сохранение/загрузка списка на диск C#

Tags: c#, файлы, коллекции, шифрование

Имеется список объектов `List<User>`. Объекты имеют вид:

```
 public class User
{
    public string WindowsUserName { get; }
    public string Login { get; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; }
    private List<Addin> LicenseList;    
}
```

Нужно зашифровать эти данные и записать в файл, а также реализовать обратный процесс. Вообще не могу разобраться как это сделать и что использовать...

Comment: Что сами пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант такие данные можно преобразовывать в XML, затем зашифровывать и сохранять в файл. Вот небольшой пример на эту тему

[image: Пример работы программы]

Возьмем такой класс пользователя

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string SaltedHashedPassword { get; set; }
}
```

И создадим для него такой класс, который будет отслеживать пользователей, проверять их пароль и имя, создавать нового пользователя, создавать соль для пароля и вычислять хэш пароля нового пользователя

```
public class UsersService
{
    //словарь всех пользователей
    private Dictionary<string, User> _usersDict = new Dictionary<string, User>();

    //ctor
    public UsersService(IEnumerable<User> usersList)
    {
        if (usersList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(usersList));

        foreach (User user in usersList)
        {
            _usersDict.Add(user.Name, user);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение всех зарегистрированных пользователей
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return _usersDict.Values.ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание экземпляра нового пользователя
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">имя пользователя</param>
    /// <param name="password">пароль</param>
    /// <returns>экземпляр нового пользователя</returns>
    /// <exception cref="UserHasWrongNameException"/>
    public User GetNewUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(username));
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(password));

        //проверяем, что такого пользователя еще нет
        if (_usersDict.ContainsKey(username)) throw new UserHasWrongNameException("Пользователь с таким именем уже существует.");

        //-- генерируем соль из массива случайных байт 
        RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[16];
        rng.GetBytes(saltBytes); //заполнение массива случайными байтами
        string salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);

        //вычисляем хэш пароля
        string saltedhashedPassword = GetSaltedHashedPassword(password, salt);

        //создаем нового пользователя
        var user = new User
        {
            Name = username,
            Salt = salt,
            SaltedHashedPassword = saltedhashedPassword
        };

        //добавляем нового в словарь
        _usersDict.Add(user.Name, user);

        return user;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получение пользователя по его имени и паролю
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">имя пользователя</param>
    /// <param name="password">пароль пользователя</param>
    /// <returns>экземпляр пользователя из списка пользователей</returns>
    /// <exception cref="UserNotFoundException" />
    /// <exception cref="UserHasWrongPasswordException" />
    public User GetUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(username));
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(password));

        //проверяем, что такой пользователь есть
        if (!_usersDict.ContainsKey(username)) throw new UserNotFoundException();

        //извлекаем пользователя
        var result = _usersDict[username];
        //получаем хэш пароля
        string hash = GetSaltedHashedPassword(password, result.Salt);

        //проверяем совпадение хэшей и отдаем результат
        if (!hash.Equals(result.SaltedHashedPassword)) throw new UserHasWrongPasswordException();
        return result;
    }

    private string GetSaltedHashedPassword(string password, string salt)
    {
        //-- объединяем пароль с солью и в массив байт
        string saltedPassword = String.Concat(password, salt);
        byte[] saltedPasswordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(saltedPassword);

        //-- вычисляем хэш для пароля с солью
        SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create();
        byte[] saltedPasswordHashBytes = sha.ComputeHash(saltedPasswordBytes);
        string result = Convert.ToBase64String(saltedPasswordHashBytes);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Создадим класс, который список пользователей будет сериализовывать в XML и обратно десериализовывать в список пользователей.

```
public class UserXmlFormatService
{
    private const string _ROOT_XML = "users";
    private const string _ELEMENT_XML = "user";
    private const string _NAME_XML = "name";
    private const string _SALT_XML = "salt";
    private const string _PASSWORD_XML = "password";


    /// <summary>
    /// Получение списка пользователей в виде строки в формате XML
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="users">коллекция пользователей</param>
    /// <returns>строка в формате XML</returns>
    public static string GetXmlFromUsers(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        if (users == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(users));

        XElement root = new XElement(_ROOT_XML);

        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            var element = new XElement(_ELEMENT_XML,
                                new XElement(_NAME_XML, user.Name),
                                new XElement(_SALT_XML, user.Salt),
                                new XElement(_PASSWORD_XML, user.SaltedHashedPassword));

            root.Add(element);
        }

        return root.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Извлечение списка пользователей из строки в формате XML
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlData">строка в формате XML</param>
    /// <returns>пользователи</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<User> GetUsersFromXml(string xmlData)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlData)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(xmlData));

        List<User> result = new List<User>();

        XElement root = XElement.Parse(xmlData);
        foreach (XElement element in root.Elements(_ELEMENT_XML))
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                Name = element.Element(_NAME_XML).Value,
                Salt = element.Element(_SALT_XML).Value,
                SaltedHashedPassword = element.Element(_PASSWORD_XML).Value
            };

            result.Add(user);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Затем будем это дело перед сохранением в файл шифровать, ну, или после чтения файла обратно расшифровывать с помощью следующ. класса.

```
public class CryptoService
{
    private readonly int _iterations = 2000;
    private byte[] _salt;
    private string _password;

    //ctor
    public CryptoService(string salt, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(salt)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salt));
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));

        _salt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
        _password = password;
    }

    private Aes GetAesInstance()
    {
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_password, _salt, _iterations);

        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
        aes.IV = pbkdf2.GetBytes(16);
        return aes;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Шифрование
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainText"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);

        Aes aes = GetAesInstance();

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Дешифровка
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cryptoText"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string Decrypt(string cryptoText)
    {
        byte[] cryptoBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoText);

        Aes aes = GetAesInstance();

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(cryptoBytes, 0, cryptoBytes.Length);
        }

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }

}
```

Весь пример можно скачать и посмотреть [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/mIBgeM893QgfaC).