# Проблема в реализации алгоритма шифрования RC5

Tags: c#, криптография

Перед вами реализация алгоритма шифрования RC5 на языке C#, найденная на просторах интернета. Функция Main дописана мной. На выводе получается "<ШdЗ%Е©ЭъИБ‚rF   " далее нулевые значения. Т. е. некоторое кол-во байт шифруются, а остальные зануляются. Содержимое файла input.txt не принципиально.

Как мне кажется, по алгоритму проходит только один блок (16 байт), а далее нулевые значения.  Почему?

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace RC5
{
    public class RC5
    {
        const int W = 64; // половина длины блока в битах. 
                          // Возможные значения 16, 32 и 64. 
                          // Для эффективной реализации величину W 
                          // рекомендуют брать равным машинному слову. 
                          // Например, для 64-битных платформ оптимальным будет
                          // выбор W=64, что соответствует размеру блока в 128 бит.

        const int R = 16; // число раундов. Возможные значения 0…255. 
                          // Увеличение числа раундов обеспечивает увеличение 
                          // уровня безопасности шифра. Так, если R = 0, 
                          // то информация шифроваться не будет.

        const UInt64 PW = 0xB7E151628AED2A6B; // 64-битная константа
        const UInt64 QW = 0x9E3779B97F4A7C15; // 64-битная константа

        UInt64[] L; // массив слов для секретного ключа пользователя
        UInt64[] S; // таблица расширенных ключей
        int t; // размер таблицы
        int b; // длина ключа в байтах. Возможные значения 0…255.
        int u; // кол-во байтов в одном машинном слове
        int c; // размер массива слов L

        public RC5(byte[] key)
        {
            /* 
            * Перед непосредственно шифрованием или расшифровкой данных выполняется процедура расширения ключа.
            * Процедура генерации ключа состоит из четырех этапов:
            * 1. Генерация констант
            * 2. Разбиение ключа на слова
            * 3. Построение таблицы расширенных ключей
            * 4. Перемешивание
            */

            // основные переменные
            UInt64 x, y;
            int i, j, n;

            /* 
            * Этап 1. Генерация констант
            * Для заданного параметра W генерируются две псевдослучайные величины,
            * используя две математические константы: e (экспонента) и f (Golden ratio).
            * Qw = Odd((e - 2) * 2^W;
            * Pw = Odd((f - 1) * 2^W;
            * где Odd() - это округление до ближайшего нечетного целого.
            * 
            * Для оптимизации алгоритма эти 2 величины определены заранее (см. коснстанты выше).
            */

            /*
            * Этап 2. Разбиение ключа на слова
            * На этом этапе происходит копирование ключа K[0]..K[255] в массив слов L[0]..L[c-1], где
            * c = b/u, а u = W/8. Если b не кратен W/8, то L[i] дополняется нулевыми битами до ближайшего 
            * большего размера c, при котором длина ключа b будет кратна W/8.
            */

            u = W >> 3;
            b = key.Length;
            c = b % u > 0 ? b / u + 1 : b / u;
            L = new UInt64[c];

            for (i = b - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                L[i / u] = ROL(L[i / u], 8) + key[i];
            }

            /* Этап 3. Построение таблицы расширенных ключей
            * На этом этапе происходит построение таблицы расширенных ключей S[0]..S[2(R + 1)], 
            * которая выполняется следующим образом:
            */

            t = 2 * (R + 1);
            S = new UInt64[t];
            S[0] = PW;
            for (i = 1; i < t; i++)
            {
                S[i] = S[i - 1] + QW;
            }

            /* Этап 4. Перемешивание
            * Циклически выполняются следующие действия:
            */

            x = y = 0;
            i = j = 0;
            n = 3 * Math.Max(t, c);

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                x = S[i] = ROL((S[i] + x + y), 3);
                y = L[j] = ROL((L[j] + x + y), (int)(x + y));
                i = (i + 1) % t;
                j = (j + 1) % c;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Циклический сдвиг битов слова влево
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">машинное слово: 64 бита</param>
        /// <param name="offset">смещение</param>
        /// <returns>машинное слово: 64 бита</returns>
        private UInt64 ROL(UInt64 a, int offset)
        {
            UInt64 r1, r2;
            r1 = a << offset;
            r2 = a >> (W - offset);
            return (r1 | r2);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Циклический сдвиг битов слова вправо
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">машинное слово: 64 бита</param>
        /// <param name="offset">смещение</param>
        /// <returns>машинное слово: 64 бита</returns>
        private UInt64 ROR(UInt64 a, int offset)
        {
            UInt64 r1, r2;
            r1 = a >> offset;
            r2 = a >> (W - offset);
            return (r1 | r2);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Свертка слова (64 бит) по 8-ми байтам
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="b">массив байтов</param>
        /// <param name="p">позиция</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static UInt64 BytesToUInt64(byte[] b, int p)
        {
            UInt64 r = 0;
            for (int i = p + 7; i > p; i--)
            {
                r |= (UInt64)b[i];
                r <<= 8;
            }
            r |= (UInt64)b[p];
            return r;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Развертка слова (64 бит) по 8-ми байтам
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">64-битное слово</param>
        /// <param name="b">массив байтов</param>
        /// <param name="p">позиция</param>
        private static void UInt64ToBytes(UInt64 a, byte[] b, int p)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                b[p + i] = (byte)(a & 0xFF);
                a >>= 8;
            }
            b[p + 7] = (byte)(a & 0xFF);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Операция шифрования
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inBuf">входной буфер для шифруемых данных (64 бита)</param>
        /// <param name="outBuf">выходной буфер (64 бита)</param>
        public void Cipher(byte[] inBuf, byte[] outBuf)
        {
            UInt64 a = BytesToUInt64(inBuf, 0);
            UInt64 b = BytesToUInt64(inBuf, 8);

            a = a + S[0];
            b = b + S[1];

            for (int i = 1; i < R + 1; i++)
            {
                a = ROL((a ^ b), (int)b) + S[2 * i];
                b = ROL((b ^ a), (int)a) + S[2 * i + 1];
            }

            UInt64ToBytes(a, outBuf, 0);
            UInt64ToBytes(b, outBuf, 8);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Операция расшифрования
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inBuf">входной буфер для шифруемых данных (64 бита)</param>
        /// <param name="outBuf">выходной буфер (64 бита)</param>
        public void Decipher(byte[] inBuf, byte[] outBuf)
        {
            UInt64 a = BytesToUInt64(inBuf, 0);
            UInt64 b = BytesToUInt64(inBuf, 8);

            for (int i = R; i > 0; i--)
            {
                b = ROR((b - S[2 * i + 1]), (int)a) ^ a;
                a = ROR((a - S[2 * i]), (int)b) ^ b;
            }

            b = b - S[1];
            a = a - S[0];

            UInt64ToBytes(a, outBuf, 0);
            UInt64ToBytes(b, outBuf, 8);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            byte[] decipher = new byte[100];
            byte[] key = new byte[10];
            //  генерация ключа
            for (byte k = 1; k < key.Length; k++)
                key[k] = k;

            RC5 session = new RC5(key);
            byte[] buffer = null;

            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

                long numBytes = new FileInfo("input.txt").Length;
                buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

                br.Close();
                fs.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Чтение из файла завершено успешно.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Чтение из файла не удалось: {0}", e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            RC5 session2 = new RC5(key);
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("cipher.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

                long numBytes2 = new FileInfo("input.txt").Length;
                byte[] cipher = new byte[numBytes2];
                session.Cipher(buffer, cipher);

                for (int i = 0; i < numBytes2; i++)
                {

                    bw.Write(cipher[i]);
                }
                bw.Close();
                fs.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Запись в файл cipher.txt завершено успешно.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Запись в файл не удалась: {0}", e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сомнительная строка: `long numBytes = new FileInfo("input.txt").Length;` этот размер нельзя использовать для размера массива буфера. Надо сначала прочитать весь текст из файла, а потом сделать так: `byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);`

Comment: Заменил сомнительную строку на реальный размер файла (384 байта), ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Вот посмотрите др. [пример RC5](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=22518&av=32506). А вам действительно принципиален именно этот алгоритм? В последних книгах всячески рекомендуют использовать AES, посмотрите на готовый пример класса [`CryptoService`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759487/222542)

Answer (score 1):

Там ведь даже в комментариях написано:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Операция шифрования
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inBuf">входной буфер для шифруемых данных (64 бита)</param>
    /// <param name="outBuf">выходной буфер (64 бита)</param>
```

Хотя здесь ошибка, оно шифрует первые 128 бит (16 байт), а не 64. Или модифицируйте этот код, или ищите другую реализацию.